# How to display the kendo loading icon while kendo-grid is loading?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, grid

I am working with Angular 5 and using the awesome Kendo Grid component. There is something I haven't gotten to work and that is to display a loading indicator in the table body while data is being retrieved. Right now, it just says "No records available". When data is retrieved, it displays them. A better user experience would be to show the kendo loading indicator just like Kendo Upload.

How do I do this?

Thank you

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21114819/kendo-ui-grid-not-showing-spinner-load-icon-on-initial-read

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example, demonstrating how to show/hide a loading indicator via custom logic, based on the mechanics of how is the Grid data retrieved.

For consistency, you can use the [Kendo UI styling](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/styling/icons/#toc-loading-indicator) for a loading indicator, but you can also use any other loading mask in accordance with your preference and requirements.

http://plnkr.co/edit/ouhC4423oiJn7pVsycRv?p=preview

Main points of interest are wrapping the Grid and the mask element (the one to be displayed conditionally - *ngIf="service.isLoading" class="k-i-loading") in a common parent, and styling the mask element to cover the parent.

```
 <div class="grid-wrapper">
       <kendo-grid
          [data]="view | async"
          [pageSize]="state.take"
          [skip]="state.skip"
          [sort]="state.sort"
          [sortable]="true"
          [pageable]="true"
          [scrollable]="'none'"
          (dataStateChange)="dataStateChange($event)"
        >
        <kendo-grid-column field="CategoryID" width="100"></kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="CategoryName" width="200"></kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="Description" [sortable]="false">
        </kendo-grid-column>
      </kendo-grid>
      <div *ngIf="service.isLoading" class="k-i-loading"></div>
      </div>
    `,
    styles: [`
    .grid-wrapper {
      position: relative;
    }
      .k-i-loading {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        font-size: 64px;
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.3);
        color: #ff6757;
      }
    `]
```

The example above relies on the data service to show the spinner while new data is loading, and hide it when loading has finished, but you can use any other logic in accordance with your requirements to toggle the boolean value the *ngIf structural directive of the mask element is bound to.

Comment: This works. I initially thought there would be something more integrated into the grid itself.

Comment: This is awesome.  Thanks!

Comment: In recent Grid versions there is a built-in loading indicator too:

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/data-binding/#toc-indicating-ongoing-data-operations

Comment: Hi topalkata! Regarding the example https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/data-binding/#toc-indicating-ongoing-data-operations I created  demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h2trw9?file=app/app.component.ts where everything seems to work fine. However, in this demo (master-detail grid) https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8g88yu?file=app/app.component.ts the pager is not covered by the loading indicator, even if kendo-pager has not been marked up in html (just the built-in paging). The pager needs to be disabled as well. How can I solve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can now simply use loading property of kendo grid component

```
<kendo-grid [loading]="variable">
</kendo-grid>
```